# Efficient Inverse computation of block matrix with off-diagonal diagonal blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{A}_{11} & \mathbf{D}_{12} & \mathbf{D}_{13} \\
    \mathbf{D}_{12} & \mathbf{A}_{22} & \mathbf{D}_{23} \\
    \mathbf{D}_{13} & \mathbf{D}_{23} & \mathbf{A}_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{A}_{ii}$ is a full matrix and $\mathbf{D}_{ij}$ is a diagonal matrix, with $i,j= 1,2,3$.

How to efficiently compute (computationally speaking) $\mathbf{M}^{-1}$?

Comment: Matrix equations such as the Sylverster matrix equation can be formulated as a standard linear system using the Kronecker product. In this case, the relevant matrix has exactly the structure which you describe.

Comment: The problem is that $\mathbf{D}_{ij}$ is a diagonal matrix where every diagonal entry has (generally) a different value. Thus, I don't think it is possible to use the property of the  Kronecker product.

Comment: In a particular case $\mathbf{M}$ can be written as: 

\begin{equation} 
 \mathbf{M}=\mathbf{P1}_{n\times n}\otimes\mathbf{D1}_{l\times l}+\mathbf{P2}_{n\times n}\otimes\mathbf{D2}_{l\times l}+\mathbf{1}_{n\times n}\otimes\mathbf{B}_{l\times l}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{B}_{l\times l}$ is a full matrix and 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{D1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{Da}_{l/2\times l/2} & 0  \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\mathbf{D2}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & \mathbf{Db}_{l/2\times l/2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}  $\mathbf{Da}$ and $\mathbf{Db}$ are diagonal matrices

Comment: What are $P1$ and $P2$? Perhaps the smallest nontrivial example should be included in the question.

Comment: P1 and P2 are symmetric full matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no trick that will allow you to utilized this structure under the stated general assumptions.

You question implies that $M$ is nonsingular and that you have enough memory to store the inverse matrix $M^{-1}$ explicitly.

I will assume that that the matrix has an LU factorization. In this case, you do a partitioned LU factorization, but fill-in will destroy the diagonal structure of the off diagonal blocks.

I will show how to derive a partitioned $LU$ factorization. Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$ be a block matrix. We want $A = LU$ where 
$$ L = \begin{bmatrix} L_{11} & 0  \\ L_{21} & L_{22} \end{bmatrix}, \quad U =  \begin{bmatrix} U_{11} & U_{12} \\ 0 & U_{22} \end{bmatrix}.$$
By explicitly multiplying $L$ and $U$ together and comparing with $A$ we deduce
$$ L_{11} U_{11} = A_{11}, \: L_{21} U_{11} = A_{21}, \: L_{11} U_{12} = A_{12}, \: L_{21} U_{12} + L_{22} U_{22} = A_{22}.$$
From this an algorithm emerges,

1. Compute LU factorization $A_{11} = L_{11} U_{11}.$
2. Compute $L_{21}= A_{21} U_{11}^{-1}.$
3. Compute $U_{12} = L_{11}^{-1} A_{12}.$
4. Update $A_{22} \gets A_{22} - L_{21} U_{12}.$
5. Compute $LU$ factorization of $A_{22}$.